# Login system, PDO and me

Tags: php, pdo, authentication

I have run into a bit of a dilemma.  Binding user input and building a prepared statement is all well and good, but what if I need the user input as a variable for a compare?

Can I just create a function to clean the input?

This is the line that worries me:

```
$password = $_POST['password']
```

What I have working so far:

```
// QUERY
public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

// RESULT SET
public function resultset(){
$this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// EXECUTE
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

**Check that the password matches with the database password if username exists**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $dbpass = '';
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Select username, password, salt and active
    $database->query('SELECT username, password, salt, active FROM wcx_admin WHERE username = :username');

    $database->bind(':username', $_POST['username']);

    $rows = $database->resultset();

    if(isset($rows[0])) {
        $salt = $rows[0]['salt'];
        $dbpass = $rows[0]['password'];
        $password = hash("sha512", $password . $salt);
    }
    if($password !== $dbpass) {
        echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
    } 
}

?>
```

**Binding Function**

```
// BIND
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
if (is_null($type)) {
    switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}
$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Can you explain why you feel i should read that?

Comment: Because it will prevent you from screwing up password hashing.

Comment: So this `$password = hash("sha512", $password . $salt);` is wrong? it should be `password_hash("sha512", $password . $salt);` ?

Comment: Read the link instead of guessing

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php - this is where i got my info from for the hash

Comment: Nowhere on that page in the official texts is it suggested to use it for hashing *passwords*.

Comment: Ok, so password_hash is obviously the one to go for but hash works the same if i add salt?

Comment: @CodeX the document he suggested is really good.

Comment: Not doesn't work the same at all. `sha*` is never meant for hashing passwords. I also doubt your salt is really random. passhash uses a slow algo, multiple rounds with a random salt.

Comment: Ok, ill change that then, i was using `$salt = rand(11111111,99999999);` for a while but now use `$salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);` Do i still need to sanitize the `$_POST['password']` before using it in a variable, if so whats the best practice here

Comment: Yeah that is not really random at all. And no just feed the password into the function. Sanitizing password is really bad either. Also I fail to see why it is needed at all.

Comment: `$password = $_POST['password']` Doesn't pose any security issues as a straight user input? "Sanitizing password is really bad either." :/

Comment: Thankyou, its so much easier with `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` i can get rid of salt now too!

Answer (score 2):

You should also make heavy use of the filter functions of PHP.

```
<?php

if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "form_id", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW) === filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, "form_id", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW)) {
  $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
  $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

  if ($username && $password) {
    $database->query("SELECT `username`, `password`, `active` FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password LIMIT 1");
    $database->bind(":username", $username);
    $result = $database->resultset();

    if (isset($result[0]) && password_verify($password, $result[0]["password"])) {
      echo "Welcome!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ive never seen these, ill check them out, thanks for the info!

Comment: Note that I changed the `INPUT_COOKIE` to `INPUT_POST`. The `form_id` is used to protect your form from manipulation (CSRF). Usually not used for login forms, but I though I include it.